# If a cell in range of cells in Excel contains an email address (@ sign), I want to move whole cell text into a different column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with lists of names, emails and addresses. What i'd like to do is search column F and if the cell contains an "@" (an email) i want to copy that cell to column D. If its blank or contains any other value, do nothing.

Is this possible in a function?

Comment: I think you need 2 try harder before create a question like this.

Answer (score 4):

In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("@",F1)),F1,"")
```

and copy down